# Converting List<List<Parts>> Grid to char C#

Tags: c#

i am creating a Sokoban game (google if needed) in C# and am trying to get my IsFinishedLevel function working.

these are my idea behind it

background is: Parts.Goal and PlayerOnGoal are parts of the game

my level for this game is stored in this

```
public List<List<Parts>> Grid { get { return grid; } }
```

this is my try for creating the isFinished method

```
public bool IsFinished()
    {
        bool Result = true;
         for (int i = 0; i < Grid.ToString().Length; i++)
         {
             if (charLevel == (char)Parts.Goal || charLevel == (char)Parts.PlayerOnGoal)
             {
                 Result = false;
             }
         }           
        return Result;
    }
```

and this is what i have trying to convert it to a char

```
    public string stringLevel;
    public char charLevel;

    public void StringGrid()
    {
        stringLevel = String.Concat(string.Empty, Grid.ToArray());
    }      
    public void CharLevel()
    {
        charLevel = Convert.ToChar(stringLevel);
    }
```

stringLevel is coming back as null.

HELP!!!!!

Comment: Do you call StringGrid before CharLevel?

Comment: `List<List<Parts>> Grid` and `Grid.ToString()`? That won't work. Do you have a rough idea on what you're doing there?

Comment: You'd better define an Array for your grid: `Parts[,]` This way you can access the Parts directly and more easy. Moving an gameobject to the nextdoor grid cell will be easier.

Comment: probably, `Parts[][] grid` (*jagged* array) is even better than *2d* `Parts[,]` one

Answer (score 1):

Well, It seems I really want my *crystal ball* in order to *reverse engineering* the problem: you have

```
public List<List<Parts>> Grid { get { return grid; } }
```

where `Parts` can be `Parts.Goal`, `Parts.PlayerOnGoal` etc. and you want to implement a method

```
public bool IsFinished()
```

which should detect if any `Parts.PlayerOnGoal` are in the `Grid` (i.e. if player has reached his/her goal whenever the goal is). If it's your *actual problem*, the solution can be something like this:

```
public bool IsFinished() {
  return Grid
    .SelectMany(list => list) // flatten the list
    .Any(parts => (char) parts == (char) Parts.PlayerOnGoal);
}
```

If you want to represent the entire `Grid` as a `string`:

```
// glue all the lines together
string grid = string.Concat(Grid  
  .SelectMany(list => list)
  .Select(parts => (char)parts));
```

Or (separating line from line)

```
string grid = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Grid
  .Select(line => string.Concat(line
     .Select(parts => (char) parts))));
```

As for

```
public string stringLevel;

charLevel = Convert.ToChar(stringLevel);
```

I have no chance to help you out. What is the *expected* result? What is `stringLevel` *domain*: can we have, say, `stringLevel == "level 12"` or `stringLevel == "123"`? What should be the `charLevel` then? `(char) 12`?